# Find multiple row and column combinations in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following matrix:

```
>> MatrixA = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16]
MatrixA =
     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12
    13    14    15    16
```

I want to find the following:

- for row 1, I want the 2nd column
- for row 2, I want the 3rd column
- for row 3, I want the 4th column
- for row 4, I want the 4th column

Currently I accomplish this with the following line:

```
>>diag(MatrixA([1 2 3 4], [2 3 4 4]))
ans =
     2
     7
    12
    16
```

Is there a more direct way to do this (without using `diag`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could use `sub2ind`, it might be more intuitive. I don't think there is much benefit though, maybe it's more readable:

```
ind = sub2ind(size(MatrixA), [1 2 3 4], [2 3 4 4])
MatrixA(ind)
```

Comment: FYI this approach has less overhead. The `diag` approach creates a _matrix_ first (and then reduces it to a vector), whereas `sub2ind` creates a _vector_ right from the start. This could be significant for large matrices.

Comment: @EitanT: I put both solutions in a `for` loop and ran them 100,000 times.  The `sub2ind` solution took 1.6 seconds to execute.  The `diag` solution took 0.12 seconds.  Would the overhead issue play a bigger role in the time to execute if the matrix was much larger?

Comment: I also get that `sub2ind` is slower than `diag`, but only ~1.5 times. Maybe it's a memory-speed tradeoff... interesting.

Comment: JIT and `diag` is a native function (in recent versions of Matlab) whereas `sub2ind` is not.

Comment: @EitanT: Yes, `sub2ind` should really be native. Old non-native versions of `diag` used to be so slow that that I'd often replace the function with `A(1:sz+1:end)`, but now even that is slower for large matrices compared to `diag`. I also wouldn't be surprised if the JIT handles `diag(diag(A))` specially.